# C# webservice client not working with a java server

Tags: c#, java, web-services, client

I am developing a webservice, it is java in the server, and must be c# in the client.
There is just one String as in parameter and as out parameter it will return an "object" with this structure:

- String codError
- String descError
- Object2[] arrayData

being "Object2" like this:

- String firstDataArray
- Int secondDataArray

I created a java client and it works flawlessly, but the c# client does not work. It says that the "EndElement" of the object was not expected (meaning the end of the object, not object2), and that it was expected a "codError" element.

The method does NOT return an array of Objects, just one Object.

I used httpanalyzer, and as well from the java client as from the c# client, the server retuns a well formed xml, and its contain is what it is supposed to be (in both clients).

I am using eclipse and axis2 for java, and visual studio 2005 and 2008 for c#.

What could be wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The c# wsdl engine might not understand the java interpretation of the wsdl file leading to these subtle bugs. Create a simpler webservice and expand from that to understand what's going wrong. Its probably something simple like c# expecting a field where its an array.

Comment: WSDL notation: don't use arrays like `Object2[]` instead use `List<Object2>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the auto-generated WSDL by axis and eclipse was wrong, and so, the XML sent from the server to the client was also wrong.
I think it is a common problem when creating the webservices bottom-up. It is much better create them top-down.

The XML that the server was sending to the client was something like (just the wrong part):

```
<descError>OK</descError>
<codError>0</codError>
<object2>
    <object2>
        <firstDataArray>John</firstDataArray>
        <secondDataArray>35</secondDataArray>
    </object2>
    <object2>
        <firstDataArray>Andrew</firstDataArray>
        <secondDataArray>76</secondDataArray>
    </object2>
    <object2>
        <firstDataArray>Walter</firstDataArray>
        <secondDataArray>23</secondDataArray>
    </object2>
</object2>
```

There is a "object2" tag there, that should not be.
It works creating a client for java using eclipse, but it does not in c#

I just made the same web service using the top-down implementation and it works great now!!

Thaks a lot to everyone!!

Answer (score 0):

because the meta data type is all different with java and C#,so,you can't throught java's datatype to c#.

I suggest you return XML data format to use.

Answer (score 0):

(Make an AXIS-Java-Server and) create the C#-Client with the WSDL of the Java-Server. There is a tool to create C#-classes of the Java server in the Visual Studio command prompt, named `SvcUtil.exe`

This works like a charm.